# stop polling when data is obtained in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that fetches data on componentDidMount. When I receive the data, I want to make another call where I will be polling data. It works currently but the polling does not stop, it keeps polling after a given delay. How can I fix this.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getResults(); // returns data.res
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps): void {
    if (!(this.props.data && this.props.data.res)) {
      this.intervalID = window.setInterval(() => this.handlePolling(), 30000);
    }
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.clearInterval(this.intervalID);
  }
```

Comment: We can't help you unless you show us the code for `getResults()` and `handlePolling()`.

Comment: But if I were to take a guess, your `getResults()` needs to return a promise, in the `.then()` call of this promise, you can make another call to `window.clearInterval(this.intervalID);`.

Comment: have you tried clearing the interval as your else statement in ```componentDidUpdate``` ?

Comment: getResults(), is an action from redux. I am using redux-saga. handlePolling, simple take a payload then call another redux action to make a call to the server.

Comment: @blankart yes, I did and I did not call the handlePolling method.